# A error about pyuic4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyuic

I'm trying to transform my ui file to .py file, but when I run pyuic4 in the shell, I get an error:

```
# pyuic4 main.ui > main_ui.py
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py", line 2
exec /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py ${1+"$@"}
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

my os is fedora16

Comment: I'm seeing the same strange error, also with fedora 16.  Somehow the pyuic directory (and possibly others?) didn't install properly.  Somehow the contents of pyuic.py is replaced with the shell script seen above.  That means the shell script is essentially pointing to itself! It would be infinite recursion, but it just crashes instead because a shell script isn't valid python syntax.  Anyone know what causes this?

Comment: @superbatfish. Surely it's no coincidence that both you and the OP are using fedora 16? Maybe you should trying posting a report on fedora's bug tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, `pyuic4` should be a bash script that would usually be installed as `/usr/bin/pyuic4`.

The error

```
exec /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py ${1+"$@"}
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

would be produced if you attempted to run that bash script with python.

However, the error message also gives the source file location as

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py", line 2
```

which doesn't make much sense, because that should be a python script.

Has `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py` somehow been over-written with the bash script?

Try opening that file, and also `/usr/bin/pyuic4`, in an editor to see what they contain.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use python2, just type

```
python2-pyuic4 main.ui > main_ui.py
```